# how to use x264 dll in another project

Tags: qt, dll, makefile, x264, libx264

I want to use x264 in my project. There is some line in the code said:

`/* Application developers planning to link against a shared library version of

- libx264 from a Microsoft Visual Studio or similar development environment
- will need to define X264_API_IMPORTS before including this header.
- This clause does not apply to MinGW, similar development environments, or non
- Windows platforms. */`

But I don't get this line:
define X264_API_IMPORTS before including this header

We can create x264 dll by its configuration and make

```
    ./configure --enable-shared
    make
```

but I can not use the dll in my Qt Project.

I can make my own dll (in another code) and use it in the project.
But when I start to use x264 dll in my project I get the following error:

```
    C:\DataHiding\SourceCode2\GUI\DataHiding\mainwindow.cpp:10: error:
    'pulldown_frame_duration' was not declared in this scope
    qDebug() << pulldown_frame_duration[1];
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

"define X264_API_IMPORTS before including this header" means that you should put this line:

```
#define X264_API_IMPORTS
```

right before this line:

```
#include <x264.h>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but adding this line to my code, didn't help and I still get the same error:

`error: undefined reference to x264_encoder_test(int)`

Comment: @user3604079 Both your errors don't have anything to do with libx264. There is no symbols pulldown_frame_duration or x264_encoder_test in libx264 so all this references (errors) are in **your** calling code.

Comment: @legoscia Imagine I want to add my own function to the dll, and make the dll again.
I tried x264 functions and I got the same error.